# My AlarmManager triggers every time service is run, not at set time

Tags: android, service, calendar, sms, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a SMS-app which sends out SMS at one set time of day. For this I have created two services SendMessagePeriodicService and SendMessageService.

This is my SendMesagePeriodicService, which is supposed to trigger SendMessageService at a set time of day. The problem is that it triggers every time the onStartCommand-method is called...

```
public class SendMessagePeriodicService extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { //FIXME

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent i =  new Intent(this, SendMessageService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,  0,  i,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getInt("minute", -1));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getInt("hour", -1));
    AlarmManager alarm  = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent); 

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
}
```

I have also checked that the values in the sharedPreferences are correct...

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reason this happens was that the time I set for trigger time was in the past. This means that AlarmManager triggers immediately and not the next time this set time occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that by setting the alarmmanager in the activity and than use BroadcastReceiver to send the sms when the alarm fires. 
I use the same technique to start a notification on a specific time.

I think I have read somewhere the you use services nowadays only for fileoperations. But I´m not 100%.

Comment: That still wouldn't answer the question as to why the AlarmManager doesn't work, though?